# Vuex - getters dynamically based on data property

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I want to add a variable to my code, so it calls different functions when I need it but it doesn't work because of the string's quotes. What type should I use or how to strip those quotes from the string?

[image]

Comment: Please don't upload [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296). They can't be copied to reproduce the issue, they aren't searchable for future readers and they are harder to read than text. Please post the actual code **as text** to create a [mcve].

Comment: Also, what is the actual property you want to access?

Comment: Your question should be *how to access vuex getters dynamically based on data property*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use brackets accessor :

```
rawData(){
  return this.$store.getters['get'+this.dataName]
}
```

`rawData` should be a computed property and `'get'+this.dataName` has to be in your getters like `getTodos`